# Apache Rewrite Rule on Dispatcher

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

How can I do a rewrite rule for both http://domain/abc to rewite/redirect to http://domain/abc.html but it should work when I have url as http://domain/abc/def.html. Currently when I do `redirect 301 "abc" "abc.hml"` the second url is also redirecting to http://domain/abc.html/def.html.

My current rules.

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/$ /content/aaa-123/abc.html [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/index.html$ /content/aaa-123/abc.html [PT,L]
RedirectMatch ^/abc$ /abc.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.(.*)$

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /content/$1/ [L]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html    
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on  
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` to match using regular expressions:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/abc/?$ /abc.html [NC,L,R=302]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^/(index\.html)?$ /content/aaa-123/abc.html [PT,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /content/$1/ [L]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this rule and do restart Apache after making these changes.

Comment: Posted my current rules.

Comment: Apache Configuration

Answer (score 1):

For the first you could use this:
    RedirectMatch ^/abc$ /abc.html

This tells apache to redirect only "/abc"

Although it sounds as you want MULTIVIEWS in Apache. Multiviews is an Option with which Apache will examine a request and add an extension if it finds a file matching the request, so if you request abc and there is abc.html it will load it.

Comment: . Request URL:http://domain.com/abc/
 . Request Method:GET
 . Status Code:403 Forbidden

Comment: which has nothing to do with a redirection. Read the Error log.